# Bootstrap Code not Displaying Correctly in Webpage

Tags: javascript, css, django, bootstrap-4, django-templates

So I am practicing working with Python and Django using Corey Schafer's YouTube series, where we are just making a blog page.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDwdMDQ8oX4&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&index=3&ab_channel=CoreySchafer

Everything was going well, but when I added the bootstrap code I noticed that my web page wasn't showing up how I expected. In the tutorial his page originally showed up exactly how mine did, but he was able to kill the terminal and refresh the page to have it load correctly. When I attempted that nothing happened. I also tried to clear my browser cache as he suggested could be a potential solution, but that didn't help much either.

Here is my main.css in my templates\blog\static\blog directory:

```
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #333333;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: #444444;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-steel {
  background-color: #5f788a;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #cbd5db;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.content-section {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.article-title {
  color: #444444;
}

a.article-title:hover {
  color: #428bca;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-content {
  white-space: pre-line;
}

.article-img {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.article-metadata {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3
}

.article-metadata a:hover {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.account-img {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.account-heading {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

And here is my base.html (in the same directory) file where we reference main.css:

```
{% load static %} 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

      <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">

    {% if title %}
        <title>Django Blog - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Django Blog</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site-header"> 
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Django Blog</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-about' %}">About</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
            <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
            <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
              </ul>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is what the page is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh3Uq.png)

[Here is how my page came out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k6Jl.png)

Unfortunately since I'm still new here I can't just add the screenshots to this post, but I am able to load the page and everything fine, but you can tell that the page is not displaying correctly. Is there something I am doing wrong? I notice this is a bit of a lengthy post but I would appreciate any help, thank you!

EDIT: [I noticed that I am getting this 404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI8fs.png)

This leads me to the assumption that there is something wrong with my implementation right? Because it's not connecting to my main.css?

Comment: While i run your code in codepen it works properly. you just need to empty cache and hard refresh your site.

Comment: I've emptied the cache, the cookies and other site data, and did a hard refresh but neither seemed to work. At least now I know for sure that the code works. Are there any other common solutions with this type of problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should try hard refresh and bypass the cache using `ctrl+f5`

For detail information: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache

Comment: I tried both and neither worked, but I just found out I'm getting a 404 error for some reason